# How to draw double y-axis barplot graph like this in pgfplot?

Tags: latex, tikz, pgfplots

I used the table data below to draw the plot using *Matplotlib*.

```
name, value_axis1, value_axis2
A,    16,          299239.74
B,    18,          292816.67
C,     3,           72799.22
D,    10,          116248.54
```

[image: Bar graph of the data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two `\begin{axis} ... \end{axis}` environments, one for the left and the other for the right. You can find the relevant part `axis y line` in the code below.

To prevent the bars from being on top of each other, `bar shift` is used (and set to the half of the `bar width` so that the bars are glued together).

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,height=8cm,compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D},
    bar width=0.6cm, bar shift=-0.3cm,
    xtick=data,
    axis y line*=left,
    ylabel=axis1,
    xlabel=name,
    ]
    \addplot[draw=red,fill=red] coordinates {
        (A,16) (B,18) (C,3) (D,10)
      };
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D},
    bar width=0.6cm, bar shift=0.3cm,
    xtick=data,
    axis y line*=right,
    ylabel=axis2
    ]
    \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (A, 299239.74) (B, 292816.67) (C, 72799.22) (D, 116248.54)
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bar plot with two y axes]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, if I set 0 for C instead of 3 then the blue bar and the red bar is not starting from the x-axis. Can you please help me with how I can fix this?

Comment: Try putting `ymin=0` to both axes, e.g., `ylabel=axis1, ymin=0,`.